# Slick: JdbcProfile has no JdbcType

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I get the Exception

```
slick.SlickException: JdbcProfile has no JdbcType for type Vector[{cardId: Int', consensusId: Int'}]
```

with the following code:

```
case class CardConsensus(cardId: Int, consensusId: Int)
case class CardConsensuses(tag: Tag) extends Table[CardConsensus](tag, Some("MagicCardDump"), "CardConsensus") {
  def cardId = column[Int]("cardId")
  def consensusId = column[Int]("consensusId")
  def * = (cardId, consensusId) <> (CardConsensus.tupled, CardConsensus.unapply)
}

val CardConsensusTable = TableQuery[CardConsensuses]

val cardConsensusQuery = CardConsensusTable.groupBy(c ⇒ c.consensusId)
val alternatives = Await.result(Db.run(cardConsensusQuery.result), 30 minutes)
```

I'm using Slick 3.0 with Postgres 9,4.

How can I rectify? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually covered in the [Slick 3.0 docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql-to-slick.html#groupby).

From those docs:

> SQL requires to aggregate grouped values. We require the same in Slick for now. This means a groupBy call must be followed by a map call or will fail with an Exception. This makes Slick’s grouping syntax a bit more complicated than SQL’s.

Hope this helps!